# TeXstudio doesn't accept memory changes

Tags: memory

I have rather big `pgfplots` in my TeX file. I'm using TeXstudio and PdfLaTeX. My PdfLaTeX command looks like follows
`pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 -main-memory=50000000 -extra-mem-top=50000000 -extra-mem-bot=50000000 -pool-size=5000000 -buf-size=5000000 %.tex`. When I want to compile the TeX-file I get the error (main.log): `! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -enable-write18 -halt-on -error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "graphics/pgfplots/main-figure4" "\def\t ikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file ' graphics/pgfplots/main-figure4' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -sh ell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or m aybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'graphics/pgfplo ts/main-figure4.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.`  and the log file of the figure tells me  `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. \pgfplotslistpushbackglobal ...e \t@pgfplots@toka`  even though I've increased the main memory.

I'm already using `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]`

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to extend the memory of the `pgfplots` library itself? And I have to stick to PdfLaTex because the template I'm using is only compatible with PdfLaTex (so LuaLaTex is no option).

A further interesting thing is, that in my MWE I can process a file of the size of around 1MB whereas I can only process a file of the size of ~120kB in my full document. The settings are the same.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}       % Zeichnungen

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,height=0.3\textheight,legend cell align=left,tick scale binop=\times}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={loosely dotted,color=darkgray!30!gray,line width=0.6pt},tick style={black,thin}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % fuer MikTex
\tikzsetexternalprefix{graphics/pgfplots/} % Ordner muss ev. zuerst haendisch erstellt werden

\title{Minimal}
\author{}
%\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \input{graphics/extfig.tex}
    \caption{caption1} 
    \label{fig:irfan} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you can process the individual plots with lualatex you can include them as pdf into a pdflatex main document, so that may be an option.

Comment: I guess that there will be some other problems like the width and overall style which is defined in the template arleady. I'd really like to avoid to work through all template files to get a second document with the same style.